# Can we find and replace a regular expression by using another regular expression in notepad?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Here i'am trying to replace some text with some another text.
Example:-

> almada-institute.com:25:info@almada-institute.com:info12345:"hello"<**service@iubi.com**>:nossl
>   in-graph.com:25:info@in-graph.com:info123456789:"hello"<**service@iubi.com**>:nossl
>   get-herbals.net:25:info@get-herbals.net:info321:"hello"<**service@iubi.com**>:nossl

I need to be like this

> almada-institute.com:25:info@almada-institute.com:info12345:"hello"<**info@almada-institute.com**>:nossl
>   in-graph.com:25:info@in-graph.com:info123456789:"hello"<**info@in-graph.com**>:nossl
>   get-herbals.net:25:info@get-herbals.net:info321:"hello"<**info@get-herbals.net**>:nossl

For this i'am using :-
[image]

**But it just replace the search content with the regular expression in replace field.**

Comment: I think you want to use group's in your find regular expression, and then in your replace with you use `\1`, `\2`, etc... To use the text matched in your group. Likely in this scenario, your can wrap your whole find in `(` `)` and the replace would be `<\1>`

Comment: @Danny now I edit my question to understand clearly what I want to do.

Comment: @Danny I want to replace second email with first email in each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex groups. Based on your sample input/output above, the below worked for me.

Find what:

```
:(\w+@.*?):(.*?)<(\w+@.*?)>:
```

Replace with:

```
:\1:\2<\1>:
```

Answer (score 2):

Use capturing groups. Putting another regex in their makes no sense. So with the screenshot you gave, the regex would be something like:

```
([a-z]\w+[@][a-z]\w+)[.]([a-z]\w+)
```

Replace with:

```
\1-\2.\1
```

Comment: According to this my second email is just replicate twice instead replaced by the first email address.

Comment: Your screenshot makes it hard to figure this out, so I had to manually type this rather than cut and paste. I think I see the mistake though and will edit. You should be able to get the idea though even if it isn't perfect.

Comment: now i get this result :- almada-institute.com:25:info@almada-institute.com:info12345:"hello"<service@iubi-.com.service@iubi>:nossl.
:(

Answer (score 2):

You can make regular expression groups by using `(` and `)` and reference then in replace using `$N`, which will access `N-th` group.

So in your case, you can do this
regex: `([^: ]+:[^:]+:([^:]+):[^:]+:[^:]+)(:[^: ]+)`
replace: `\1<\2>\3` or on some implementation `$1<$2>$3`

You can try it yourself here: https://www.regex101.com/r/hY8pY9/1